# Div display table row cell layout simple structure but not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

EDIT:
Added a demo image with a example of how I need the site layout design to looks like

I need a simple 3 column layout table like the follow one in demo, but it is not working. I uploaded a image of what I need and a demo fiddle with my result. Here is the code with css

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>title</title>
</head>

<body>


<div style="display:table;width:100%;height:100%:min-width:1000px;">

<div style="display:table-row">
  <div style="display:table-cell;width:100%;min-width:1000px;height:23px;min-height:23px;"> only 1 TD 100% width only 23 height </div>
</div>

<div style="display:table-row">
  <div style="display:table-cell;width:200px;min-width:200px;height:77px;min-height:77px;"> left 200 px width </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell;width:100%;min-width:800px;height:77px;min-height:77px;"> middle 100% of screen width </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell;width:200px;min-width:200px;height:77px;min-height:77px;"> right 200 px width</div>
</div>

<div style="display:table-row">
  <div style="display:table-cell;width:200px;min-width:200px;height:100%;min-height:100%;"> left 200 px width but height 100% </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell;width:100%;min-width:800px;height:100%;min-height:100%;"> middle 100% of screen width but height 100%  </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell;width:200px;min-width:200px;height:100%;min-height:100%;"> right 200 px width but height 100% </div>
</div>


<div style="display:table-row">
  <div style="display:table-cell;width:100%;min-width:1000px;height:12px;min-height:12px;"> only 1 TD 100% width only 12px height </div>
</div>

</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Here is an image of how I need it to looks like
[image]

And here a demo Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/yzr3v04u/

Why is not working as I want if CSS tables are the future and can be edited and placed anywhere I want them?

Any other way to do what I need in the image demo any ideas?

Comment: You should stop writing inlined CSS (style attribute) and use a stylesheet or at least write CSS rules in a style element. Here it'd allow Don't Repeat Yourself (except for mailings but still there are tools that'll inline CSS for you)

Comment: "CSS tables are the future": more like present time ;) as they're compatible with IE8+. Present time is being able to choose between different layout techniques (floats, clearfix, all values of display - table, inline-block, etc - and positioning). Present time or near future is [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (IE10+, needs a fallback in IE9 and IE8 or to allow some discrepancies if you still need to support those), now with multi-line/column wrap in nearly all browsers

Comment: The other answer is not really working 100% so the chosen correct answer is available

Answer (score 0):

There you go. Please don't use Tables to build a website layout, it's bad practice when it comes to responsive (mobile devices) design, use CSS instead.

If you want your column height to be down to the bottom of the page there are new CSS3 measurement units called [Viewport-Percentage (or Viewport-Relative) Lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

All you need to do is add `height: 100vh;` to your CSS `.content-wrapper`.

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 21px;
    background-color: orange;
}
.sub-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 79px;
    background-color: brown;
}
.content-wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh; 
}
.left-column {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
}
.middle-column {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
.right-column {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
}
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="sub-header"></div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="left-column">1</div>
    <div class="middle-column">2</div>
    <div class="right-column">3</div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: So you just don't use display table or cell or row? It looks almost nice, it just will not keep the height to 100% in left, middle and right column

Comment: It depends on your content, if you add content there it will grow accordingly. There is no need to use a table for this.

Comment: I need it to be 100% height because otherwise it show white space on bottom and looks ugly on any device. How to achive this ?

Comment: I added html, body {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-family:Tahoma;color:#333333;width:100%;height:100%;} to your css and it is working now very fine, thanks a lot amigo

Comment: last question about VH will height: 100vh; work on any device on any browser ?

Comment: Any browser that will support CSS3. Basically all major browser (any IE after version 8). Please check http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: In case the browser is old will  width: 100%;
   height: 100vh; height:100px;  work ? or is not reccomended to use both measurements?

Comment: You can only use 1 measurement unit... either `100vh` or `100px` in this case, `100px` is not going to provide a good solution for your question.
In one of the comments you posted about adding `margin: 0 ...` if that works out for you then you can use it to but I recommend sticking to CSS3 since old specs get dumped for new spec as the years go by.

Comment: we forgot in sub-header there are 3 column divs too, does I just insert those divs INLINE and make subheader act as its container as you did with content-wrapper only?

Comment: Where do you see OP using a table for layout? She/He's already using CSS (`display: table`) for that so it seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I see an error now: Middle column background edited to RED color and it does not respect the 100% width and height in red color only the number 2 is surrounded by red color... How to fix that?

Comment: If you're looking this to be good on all sorts of screen sizes you should use `%` for units so your layout is scaled according to screen size. So you just need to set `width: 20%` for example for left and right columns and `width: 60%` to middle one.
Please check this tutorial to learn more about CSS layouts: http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_layout.asp

Comment: @FelipeAls, you are right, I saw him using the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` properties and he seems to be an HTML/CSS novice so I wanted to let him now first hand that it's bad practice.